# problems using typedef struct and using the data inside

Tags: c, struct

I´m running into a problem all around my program that I dont know how to resolve. The error message that pops-up pretty much everywhere i use a variable declared in a struct is the following (example):
 In function 'nameGuy':
prog.c:42:14: error: expected expression before 'GUY'
   scanf("%s",GUY.name);

Here is the code referring to this part of the program:

```
typedef struct 
{
char *name[7];  //guy name
int level;   //guy level
int armor, weapon;  //guy equipment
int STR, MAG, HP, SPD;  //guy stats
}GUY;

void nameGuy()
{
char aux='N';

do{
    printf("\nWrite the name of your guy:  »");
    scanf("%s",GUY.name);
    printf("    Is that so? (Y/N)");
    scanf("%c",&aux);
    }while(aux!='Y');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
For further context, im trying to develop a basic text-rpg to try and sharpen my c skills, and the guy struct is supposed to be the main character.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the defined type name, as an instance of the struct which is of course invalid.

Maybe you saw this

```
struct 
{
    char *name[7];  //guy name
    int level;   //guy level
    int armor, weapon;  //guy equipment
    int STR, MAG, HP, SPD;  //guy stats
} GUY;
```

which, I don't recommend because you are declaring `GUY` as an anonymous struct and as a global variable. This would fix your problem:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char name[32];  /* guy name: don't make it so small */
     /* ^ this should be an array of char, not of pointers */
    int level;   //guy level
    int armor, weapon;  //guy equipment
    int STR, MAG, HP, SPD;  //guy stats
} GUY;

do {
    GUY guy;

    printf("\nWrite the name of your guy:  »");
    scanf("%31s", guy.name);

    printf("    Is that so? (Y/N)");
    scanf(" %c", &aux);
} while(aux!='Y');
```

Comment: you are right, i completely messed that up... i would have to declare in my main function something like GUY guy and replace GUY with guy in the scanf, is this right?

Comment: if i have to use the data in the struct in various functions, would i have to declare GUY guy; in every function? or could i just declare it in main?

Comment: No, you just need to pass it from one function to another as a parameter, using a global variable is the worst solution for this.